# To lie prone on the bed

Tags: meaning

Please explain if the sentence 
'to lie prone on the bed  with the legs up in the air bent at the knees'
 conveys the idea that someone to lie flat on the tummy in a provocative position.

Comment: I can only imagine that position being comical or awkward. Are you sure you don't mean to use the word [*supine*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supine) instead?

Comment: @Jason Bassford Although the overlap region is limited, 'prone' and 'supine' are synonyms, and interchangeable from point of view of semantics here. Perhaps not at a connotational level.

Comment: To me, "prone" does not necessarily imply laying on your stomach.  Though "on your back" or "on your stomach" removes any ambiguity.

Comment: 'To lie prone ' according to Oxford Advanced Learner's is to lie flat with the front of your body touching the ground where as 'to lie supine' means to lie flat on your back. Although in both the instances the person is in a horizontal position,  there are a clear distinctions between the two i.e face up or down and lying on the back or stomach.